# Sublime Text Emmet JSX selfClosingStyle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, sublimetext

Hello I use latest Sublime Text 4 with Emmet and reactjs source with build in `Syntax -> Javasript > JSX` and it work.

I change default emmet setting `"jsx_prefix": true,` to false, and it work - now I can expand tags without `<`.

But i want change default expand `Component/` -> `<Component>` to `<Component />`

I try change `"markup_style": "html",` to xhtml or xml but it not work.

And in emmet setting i can see this param, which maybe can solve my problem:

```
    // See `GlobalConfig` interface for supported properties: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/src/config.ts
    // Example:
    // "config": {
    //  "markup": {
    //      "snippets": {
    //          "foo": "foo.bar>baz"
    //      },
    //      "options": {
    //          "output.selfClosingStyle": "xhtml"
    //      }
    //  }
    // }
    "config": {},
```

Because I don't know TS, I can't read source in GitHub to solve this, can anyone know how to use this `config` param not for one snippet as in example, but for JSX with `"output.selfClosingStyle": "xhtml"`?

I try write something like this(but not work):

```
"config": {
        "markup": "jsx",
        "options": {
            "output.selfClosingStyle": "xhtml"
        }
    }
```

Help me to use JSX self closing tags with emmet in ST4 pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sublime Text, you can specify config either globally for syntax type (`markup` or `stylesheet`) or for specific syntax.

Syntaxes are listed in `syntax_scopes` option of Emmet config, which is a mapping of syntax name to Sublime Text internal scope (you can create your own syntaxes like this as well).

In your case, you should specify config for `jsx` syntax, like this:

```json
{
    "config": {
        "jsx": {
            "options": {
                "output.selfClosingStyle": "xhtml"
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx, but how I can use ``ctrl+e``(now not work, only tab) for expand in ``jsx`` if ``"jsx_prefix": true`` by default?